# C skipping fgets when reading a .cvs file

Tags: c, gcc

I  am reading a .cvs looking for the longest line, there's two longest lines (54 characters).
Basically I'm reading the file line by line looking for the number of characters and when I find it I wanna read the same file again and print the lines with that amount of characters.
Wild guess is that I have to flush the buffer but I dont know how.

The problem is that the program is skipping my second loop.

```
int filaMasLarga(FILE *archivo)
{

char str[1000], longest[1000];
int len = 0;
int count = 0;
char str2[1000], longest2[1000];
int len2 = 0;
int count2 = 0;

while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), archivo) != NULL) // Recorremos el fichero linea por linea.
{
    count++;
    if (count != 1)
    {
        if (len < strlen(str))
        {
            strcpy(longest, str);
            len = strlen(str);
        }
    }
}
printf("longest line length is : %i", len); //54


//Gets skipped
while (fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), archivo) != NULL) 
{
    if (len == strlen(str2))
    {
        strcpy(longest2, str2);
        printf("Linea : %s", longest2);
    }
}
fclose(archivo); 
int filaLarga = 0;
return filaLarga;
```

}

Comment: After the first loop, the reading position is at the file's end. You must `rewind(archivo)` before you can read from it again.

Comment: The issue is that the file pointer is not reset when the first loop ends, so when the second loop runs, `fgets` believes that it is already at the end of the file. The solution to this is to insert an `fseek(archivo, 0, SEEK_SET)` before the second loop will get you the result you need.

Comment: (Alternatively, you could try to do find the contents of the longest line in a single loop.)